# How to handle null strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Say I have the following code:

```
Request.QueryString["ids"].Split('|');
```

If `ids` is not present in the query string this will throw an exception.  Is there a generally accepted way to handle this type of situation.  I think all of the following options would keep this from thorwing an error, but I'm wondering if one (or some different method entirely) is generally accepted as better.

```
string[] ids = (Request.QueryString["ids"] ?? "").Split('|');
```

or

```
string[] ids;
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ids"]))
{
   ids = Request.QueryString["ids"].Split('|')
}
```

or

`?`

I think all of these will work, but they look sort of ugly.  Is there a better* way?

*better = easier to read, faster, more efficient or all of the above.

Comment: Easier to read, Faster, More Efficient.  Pick One :)

Comment: Your second option won't work, `null as string` is still null.

Comment: The `If(!String.IsNullOrEmpty`  one is the easiest to read - IMHO. Regarding speed is there a difference in the IL produced?

Comment: The soft cast (qs as string) will not work.  It will still return null.  The null-coalesce operator (??) appears to be the 'cleanest' solution IMHO.

Comment: @Lee, you were right.  Removed `null as string` option.

Comment: It's generally best to validate all of your input (check that `Request.QueryString["ids"]` is non-null, throw appropriate error messages) prior to processing it (doing the `Split()`), imho, rather than combining them like that.

Comment: Also, your first and third options are different since `ids` will be null in the third if the check fails, whereas it will be empty in the first.

Comment: @Lee, actually I think in the first one it would have one element, correct?

Comment: @AbeMiessler - Yes, you're right it would contain the empty string.

Comment: @Lee, still a good point.  Not the best example maybe, but I hope it gets the idea of what I'm asking across.

Comment: Better = stating your intent clearly. If an empty string/null has no meaning, don't propogate that assumption further into your code. Test early and don't create meaningless intermediate results (such as those caused by splitting an empty string).

Comment: Almost all cases of NullReferenceException are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I like using an extension method for this:

```
public static string EmptyIfNull(this string self)
{
    return self ?? "";
}
```

Usage:

```
string[] ids = Request.QueryString["ids"].EmptyIfNull().Split('|');
```

Comment: I don't like this. Null isn't an empty string and leads to a spurious entry in the split array. The better approach is to handle the null there and then and not to leave any assumptions to be dealt with downstream.

Comment: `Split()` returns a `string[]`. `ToArray` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd use

```
string idStr = Request.QueryString["ids"];
ids = idStr == null ? new string[0] : idStr.Split("|");
```

Comment: Good. No spurious entry caused by empty strings. +1. If it were me, I'd probably test for `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, but it's not clear whether an empty string represents a useful value to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] ids = (Request.QueryString["ids"] as string).Split('|');
```

This will fail in the same manner as `Request.QueryString["ids"]`

```
string[] ids;
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ids"]))
{
   ids = Request.QueryString["ids"].Split('|')
}
```

Heavier and may call the data retrieval logic twice (and you might have side-effects done twice by error) => use a temporary to store the data but heavier.

```
string[] ids = (Request.QueryString["ids"] ?? "").Split('|');
```

Definetely the easiest, cleanest and more efficient way as the compiler will generate a temporary itself.

If you encounter this kind of processing a lot of time you can build your own plumbing library with a bunch of methods with fluent names and behaviors.